# WPF MVVM CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I am pretty new to the MVVM style of programming. The problem I am having is that I am trying to set the property of a checkbox when the WPF window loads. I do not need the property to be able to be changed. I merely need to show that it is checked or not.

XAML:
UPDATE:

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.492,0.519" DataContext="{Binding ClosingCost}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="197"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="103"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Label x:Name="LineID" Content="LineID" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="LineName" Content="Line Name" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="ClosingCostType" Content="Closing Cost Type" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="UpdateClosingCostAuto" Content="Update Closing Cost Automatically" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="CopyEstToGFE" Content="Copy Estimate to GFE" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="CopyEsttoComparison" Content="Copy Estimate to Comparison" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="EstimateType" Content="Estimate Type" Grid.Column="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Label x:Name="LineIDResult" Content="{Binding HUDLineNo}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label x:Name="LineNameResult" Content="{Binding LineName}"/>
            <Label x:Name="ClosingCostTypeResult" Content="{Binding LineName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="UpdateClosingCostAutoResult"  Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="CopyEstToGFEResult" Content="{Binding CopyEstimateToGFE}" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CopyEsttoComparisonResult" Content="{Binding CopyEstimateToComparison}" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="EstimateTypeResult" Content="{Binding EstimateType}" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="Type" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="{Binding HUDLineNo}"/>
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

UPDATE:

```
public class EditClosingCostViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public EditClosingCostViewModel() : this(new ClosingCostDal(), new ClosingCostFilterResult())
        {

        }
        public EditClosingCostViewModel(ClosingCostDal closingCostDal, ClosingCostFilterResult closingCostFilterResult)
        {
            this.closingCostDal = closingCostDal;
            this.closingCostFilterResult = closingCostFilterResult;
        }

        private ClosingCostDal closingCostDal;
        private ClosingCostFilterResult closingCostFilterResult;

        public ClosingCostFilterResult ClosingCost
        {
            get
            {
                return closingCostFilterResult;
            }
            set
            {
                closingCostFilterResult = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ClosingCost");
            }
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                if (ClosingCost.AutoUpdate == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Not entirely sure if the ViewModel is correct or even remotely going in the right direction.

Comment: please post complete code of your view model

Comment: If you only need to bind it once, make the binding mode set to OneTime

Comment: You need to Raise propertychanged on your IsSelectedProperty.

Comment: no, he does _not_ need `INotifyPropertyChanged` _unless_ he wants to change the property from code (and update the view accordingly)

Comment: Added both comments below. The method doesn't even seem to be getting called. Put a break in the view model on the IsSelected and it's not even breaking.

Comment: I'd really like to see how the DataContext is being assigned, can we see more of your XAML (or code if you are doing it via code)?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the property from your view, a read-only property is enough.

```
public bool IsSelected { get; } = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="UpdateClosingCostAutoResult"  Grid.Column="1" enter code hereIsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneTime}" /
```

And add the **OneTime** mode in your binding

Comment: I added both your comments and Haukinger and the checkbox is still not displaying as checked. It's like the method isn't even being called. I put a break on the method and it never gets there.

Comment: Did you set the DataContext ?